# LocalDateTime.now() throwing exception when called in a JavaFX context with observer

Tags: java, javafx, observer-pattern

I'm writing a JavaFX application where the FXController is an Observer to a Different class. I need to get the last time the observer received a notification to update. The problem is I'm trying to use java8 time API, with `LocalDateTime` and everytime I'm calling `LocalDateTime.now()` it's giving me a `NullPointerException` pointing to some tzbd file which doesn't exist.

However `LocalDateTime.now()` works perfectly on my system if I just open up a console project and run the code there.

Is the problem with JavaFX then? Any workaround for this?

Code where exception is thrown :

```
public void getTimeStamp() {
    LocalDateTime c = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("Grand Total has been updated ... @ " + c);
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    grandTotal.setText(
        Integer.toString(
            controller.getReg().getGrandTotal()
        )
    );
    System.out.println("Update() called @ ");
    getTimeStamp();
}
```

Here is the full Exception StackTrace :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/lib/tzdb.dat (No such file or directory)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:261)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.<clinit>(ZoneInfoFile.java:251)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(ZoneInfo.java:589)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:560)
    at java.util.TimeZone.setDefaultZone(TimeZone.java:666)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(TimeZone.java:636)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(TimeZone.java:625)
    at java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault(ZoneId.java:274)
    at java.time.Clock.systemDefaultZone(Clock.java:178)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.now(LocalDateTime.java:180)
    at assignment.notifiers.BeepMaker.playBeep(BeepMaker.java:11)
    at assignment.controller.RegistrationFxController.calculateDiscount(RegistrationFxController.java:178)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/lib/tzdb.dat (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:255)
    ... 70 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/lib/tzdb.dat (No such file or directory)` - what JRE version are you running your code on? When I look at my source for ZoneInfoFile, it doesn't match your stacktrace.

Comment: JRE 8 u121. < OS : OpenSUSE Leap 42.2 >

Comment: And I also have this question : fine this file can't be found on OpenSUSE but I tried it out on macOS, same thing. Do you suggest a complete re-compile of the classes on a OS other than OpenSUSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I had a ConfigLoader class that was overriding `JAVA_HOME`. Used `System.setProperty(key, value)` instead of `System.setProperties(property)`